# PHP parsing html with DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get the below code to work, so that I understand what I am doing on a larger project. For the most part,I'm just trying to make sure I can grab elements by their tag. The code seems to break  at "$html = new simple_html_dom();" because if I comment that out, then I get the two print outs. but if it's not commented out, nothing shows up on the screen at all.

```
<?php
# create and load the HTML

include('simple_html_dom.php');
print "hello ";
$html = new simple_html_dom();

print "world"
#$html->load("<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>We're here</p></body></html>");

# get an element representing the second paragraph
#$element = $html->find("p");
# modify it
#$element[1]->innertext .= " and we're here to stay.";

# output it!
#echo $html->save();
?>
```

Comment: You should really set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` for development.

Comment: And `ini_set('display_errors', true);` as well.

Comment: If you see a blank page, that suggests that there's an error somewhere and you have disabled displaying errors in the browser.

You can either use `display_errors` as suggested by AlexZ or look at the server logs. The location of the logs depends on your system, but for a Linux a good place to start looking is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: My understanding is the '#' at the front of the lines that manipulate the $HTML object are commenting out the code,  so they need to be removed.  I would also check that the object creation was successful, by checking the $HTML to not be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `simple_html_dom.php` file actually exiting and loaded? You might want to write that `include` similar to:

```
<?php
if(!@file_exists('./simple_html_dom.php') ) 
{
    echo 'can not include: simple_html_dom.php';
    die();
} 
else 
{
    include('./simple_html_dom.php');
}
?>
```

So the PHP parser on the server will let you know if there is a problem.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks guys. Problem was very simple, I didn't have the simple_html_dom.php in the same directory. And turning the error checking on pointed that out.

Comment: Or use `require` instead of `include`, as it will check whether the file exists and is readable, failing with a fatal error if not.